# How to use VueI18n for component instance based internationalization?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm building Vue app without using npm. As there are too many guides referring to npm, I can not follow them correctly. So, I just included scripts like this:

```
    <script src="/js/bluebird.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/vue-i18n.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/components.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

For now I'm trying to show buttons list, by loading them from json file. That file contains array of object with info about button, including it's text on different languages. So, for now I cannot understand how to make vue-i18n load messages from that file. Basic code:

```
            <buttons-list inline-template>
                <div class="buttons-list">
                    <big-button inline-template
                        :class="[button.position, button.number]"
                        v-for="button in buttons"
                        :key="button.id"
                        :button="button">
                        <div class="big-button">{{ $t(button.text) }}</div>
                    </big-button>
                </div>
            </buttons-list>
```

buttonsList component code:

```
Vue.component('buttons-list', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            buttons: []
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        this.loadButtons()
    },
    methods: {
        loadButtons: function() {
            const list = this;
            axios.get('/json/buttons.json')
            .then(function(response) {
                list.buttons = response.data
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Here I read json file when component created, so when bigButton created, `button` property will have all required info.
bigButton component code:

```
Vue.component('big-button', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    props: ['button'],
    created: function() {            
        this.$i18n.setLocaleMessage('en', this.button.messages.en)
        this.$i18n.setLocaleMessage('ru', this.button.messages.ru)
    },
    i18n: {
        messages: {}
    }
})
```

Here, in `created` function I tried to set instance's `i18n.messages` to data from json file. Basically, this works, except it resets `messages` for all buttons to current data, ending up in all buttons having same, last button's text. 
Is it possible to work with component instances in vue-i18n? Or is there other ways I'm missing?

---

**SOLUTION**

I've changed my `bigButton` component code to:

```
Vue.component('big-button', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    props: {
        button: {
            type: Object,
            default: function() {return {}}
        },
    },
    created: function() {
        this.$i18n.setLocaleMessage('en', this.button.messages.en)
        this.$i18n.setLocaleMessage('ru', this.button.messages.ru)
    },
    i18n: {
        //i18n stops working when this block removed
    }
})
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VueI18n supports per-component localization - it is explained in the [official documentation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/component.html)
Just define `i18n`object with messages inside your component - documentation shows exactly how to do it:

```
// setup locale info for root Vue instance
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'ja',
  messages: {
    en: {
      message: {
        hello: 'hello world',
        greeting: 'good morning'
      }
    },
    ja: {
      message: {
        hello: 'こんにちは、世界',
        greeting: 'おはようございます'
      }
    }
  }
})

// Define component
const Component1 = {
  template: `
    <div class="container">
     <p>Component1 locale messages: {{ $t("message.hello") }}</p>
     <p>Fallback global locale messages: {{ $t("message.greeting") }}</p>
   </div>`,
  i18n: { // `i18n` option, setup locale info for component
    messages: {
      en: { message: { hello: 'hello component1' } },
      ja: { message: { hello: 'こんにちは、component1' } }
    }
  }
}

// template
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ $t("message.hello") }}</p>
  <component1></component1>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

How to initialize a component with unique localization strings:

```
const Component1 = {
  template: `
    <div class="container">
     <p>Component1 locale messages: {{ $t("message.hello") }}</p>
     <p>Fallback global locale messages: {{ $t("message.greeting") }}</p>
   </div>`,
  i18n: { // `i18n` option, setup locale info for component
    messages: uniqueLocalization
  },
  props:
  {
    uniqueLocalization:
    {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  }
}

<template>
  <div>
    <comp :unique-localization="locale_1"/>
    <comp :unique-localization="locale_2"/>
    <comp :unique-localization="locale_3"/>    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import component1 from '@/components/component1.vue'

export default
{
  components:
  {
    comp: component1
  },
  data()
  {
    return {
      locale_1:
      {
        en:
        {
          message:
          {
            hello: 'Greetings',
            bye: 'Farewell'
          }
        },
        ru:
        {
          message:
          {
            hello: 'Привет',
            bye: 'До свидания'
          }
        }
      },
      locale_3:
      {
        en:
        {
          message:
          {
            hello: 'Greetings, buddy',
            bye: 'Farewell, dude'
          }
        },
        ru:
        {
          message:
          {
            hello: 'Привет, ребята',
            bye: 'До свидания, мужики'
          }
        }
      },
      locale_3:
      {
        en:
        {
          message:
          {
            hello: 'Godd day, team',
            bye: 'Bye-bye, darling'
          }
        },
        ru:
        {
          message:
          {
            hello: 'Здравствуйте, братушки',
            bye: 'Пока'
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Let's say I have 10 `Component1` instances at once, which one's english text will be 'hello component1'? I need every one of them have different text and per-component localization doesn't help.

Comment: It helps but you should initialize the per-component `i18n` objects with different values - through props, AJAX, or anything else. Or, if you insist that each of the 10 components must be unique - just create 10 different components in 10 different `.vue` files each with its own localization texts.

Comment: That's the question, how to initialize component with different values? I have tried to write `i18n: {messages: this.button.messages}` with no luck.

Comment: It's strange, it doesn't work with `this.button.messages`, but works with `this.localization` when passed `button.messages` to component directly via `:localization`. Thanks for help!

Comment: This code worked, but not in the direct way. It does not work when data loaded from json file, and of course I didn't list all components directly, only via `v-for`. Looks like that problem was when I tried to pass `props` as array. When I changed it to object as in this example, it worked like a charm!